# How do I move my label frame to top right side of my window?

Tags: python, tkinter

below are my codes. I want to move my entire LabelFrame to top right. Its currently shown up right in the middle. How do I do that?

I tried using sticky = 'NW' but that didnt work

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
import openpyxl
from tkinter import *

#root = Tk()

#root.geometry("1200x800")

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("1200x800")
window.title("Data Entry Form")

frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()


# Saving User Info
user_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="User Information")
user_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

first_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="First Name")
first_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
last_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="Last Name")
last_name_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
last_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="Last Name2")
last_name_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

first_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
last_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
last_name2_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)

first_name_entry.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
last_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1,padx=5, pady=5)
last_name2_entry.grid(row=2, column=1,padx=5, pady=5)

# Set default values
first_name_entry.insert(0,"XX")
last_name_entry.insert(0,"YY")

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The answer depends on what else you're going to put in the window. Are there going to be other frames below it? To the side of it?

Comment: The problem isn't so much with  your labelframe, but rather with the placement of `frame` which is centered along the top.

Comment: hi @BryanOakley yes I intend to put few other frames like "Location Information", "Education Information" etc etc. so need to utilise the the window properly. I dont have any clue about tkinter and googling as I am building my codes. any help is most appreciated

Comment: Just saying you want other widgets isn't helpful. There are many ways to solve your problem, but it depends on _specifically_ what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want this labelframe to take up the whole right side, like a sidebar, or just the top-right corner? Are you creating a grid of multiple frames or will your frames not line up in rows and columns? Something else? It's like asking "how do I make my food sweeter?" without saying whether you're making candy, a bbq sauce, a salad, or tacos.

Comment: thanks I think I managed to sort it out by changing the  row and column values in user_info_frame. as I said I dont have any clue about this as learning as I google.  The trial and error was easier to do than to explain all over here.

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter said, the problem isn't in the placement of your `LabelFrame` but in the placement of its parent `frame`. If you use the `pack` layout manager, you can specify what `side` you want to pack the widget to and what corner you want to `anchor` it to.

So, all you need to do to get your frame in the top-right corner is this:

```
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack(side=tkinter.TOP, anchor=tkinter.NE)
```

Comment: thanks again but as I said above I could get it to work by trial and error by changing the values of row and column